# Make a folder both a symlink and a git submodule

Tags: windows, git, symlink, mklink

This my project structure in a nutshell:

```
 + A
 | + some content
 |
 + B
   + A
```

I want in my main git repo a submodule in `B` that points to `A`. But since the `A` project contains the main method, I want to be able to quickly test before committing, so I'd like a symlink (or rather a `mklink` since I'm on windows) that points to `A` so it gets updated without committing.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that A doesn't have just "some content".
It also has a `.git` subfolder in it, which a submodule does not.

If you can, use [`git worktree`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30185564/6309) in order to checkout a branch in a separate folder (than the original `A` cloned folder)

Then you can try and use a symlink from `B` subfolder to `A`, after adding `A` as a submodule in `B`.
Note: [since Windows 10 build 14972 (Dec. 2016)](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/12/02/symlinks-windows-10/), symlinks (`mklink`) can be created without needing to elevate the console as administrator.

---

A better approach is described in "[Git: Possible to use same submodule working copy by multiple projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27384763/6309)".