# How to develop/debug two apps with shared components using vue3 and vite?

Tags: vuejs3, vite

I'm building a couple of apps with vue3 and vite, using some shared components. The production build process works OK but I'm having a problem with dev/debug. The [Vite docs](https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#multi-page-app) (for multi-page apps) says

> "During dev, simply navigate or link to /nested/ - it works as
> expected, just like for a normal static file server."

but I don't know what this means - how do I link to a sub folder? I have added `/src/app1` to `url` in launch.json, but it has no effect. I have also tried using `cd src\app1` in the terminal before running `npm run dev`

```
"version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
          "type": "firefox",
          "request": "launch",
          "name": "vuejs: firefox  -width 300 -height 600 -P default",
          "url": "http://localhost:5173/src/app1",
          "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
          "pathMappings": [
            {
              "url": "file:///C:",
              "path": "c:"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
```

(This launch.json works well with a simple single-page app).

What happens with trying to debug one of the apps is that the project launches but with an empty index.html (i.e. a blank screen with no errors). I'm pretty sure the basic project structure is OK because (as I said) the build process works; I get two separate outputs of html+css+js both of which work as expected, with the correct shared components.

Also, if I [tell the Vite server](https://vitejs.dev/config/server-options.html) to automatically open the page (as I have done in my `vite.config.js` below) the page opens correctly - although without a debugger attached of course. So I guess that the settings in `launch.json` are incorrect.

The project structure is:

```
-src
 -app1
  -app.vue
  -index.html
  -main.js
 -app2
  -app.vue
  -index.html
  -main.js
 -assets
  ...
 -shared
  -components
   -shared.vue
```

If I have just one `index.html`, moved up a level, I *can* debug each app but only by editing it every time to point to a different `main.js` and to change the title, which seems a laborious way of approaching the task.

Below is my vite  config. The extra lines in `alias` were added as an attempt to solve the problem but they are probably incorrect (or unneccesary)

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'
import { resolve } from 'path'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'


// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  server: {
    base: '/src/app1',
    open: '/src/app1/index.html',
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      vue: 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js',
       '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url)),

      app1: fileURLToPath(new URL('./src/app1', import.meta.url)),
      app2: fileURLToPath(new URL('./src/app2', import.meta.url)),
      // shared: fileURLToPath(new URL('./src/shared/components', import.meta.url)),
    }
  },
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        app1: resolve(__dirname, './src/app1/index.html'),
        app2: resolve(__dirname, './src/app2/index.html'),
      },
    },
  },
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I've made things more complex than neccesary because I missed the important setting. In `vite.config.js`, it's important to define `root` to point to where each `index.html` is found. So for my structure above, the config file looks like

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue() ],
  root: "src\app1",
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      vue: 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js',
    }
  }
})
```

In the process I've also swapped from Firefox to Chrome for debug (I was getting a lot of irrelevant error messages from Firefox), and my `launch.json` is now simply

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
       {
          "type": "chrome",
          "request": "launch",
          "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
          "url": "http://localhost:5173",
          "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
        }
      ]
}
```

It doesn't really matter what the file structure looks like, as long as within each file its dependencies are correctly addressed. The only important bit is the `root`. Simply by changing that from `'app1'` to `'app2'` will switch both the debug and the build to the correct folders, with the release (built) files being stored in subfolders of 'app1' and 'app2' independently.

It would be easy to extend this to have more than 2 apps each sharing the same common components.