# git submodule in submodule with shared dependencies, in a C# project

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have this following scenario:

- a core lib, let's call it A.
- a features lib, we'll call B. B depends on A.
- a tool, called C, depending on A and B.

A is shared across many projects. B is shared across 3-4.

So, the layout is as follows:

- Project C has a submodule with A inside.
- Project C has a submodule with B inside and, in turn, B has a submodule with A inside.

This works well in git, although it fails quickly on the project side.

The first implication is that C and B could use different revisions of A, but that's just up to us to not mess that up.

The main issue is that it is not be possible to have a project including 'A' twice in the IDE.

Is it possible to have B as a submodule, but B wouldn't its own submodule? so we woudln't have two copies of A?

Additionally, I'm sure there are others with the same problem. Is there a common / accepted way to deal with that issue?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27379818/git-possible-to-use-same-submodule-working-copy-by-multiple-projects/27384763#27384763) help?

Comment: it's good info, thanks; but it doesn't totally solve the issue because there is a problem on the .net side related to this. I'm looking at ideas right now

Answer (score 1):

The common/accepted way to deal with that issue is not to use git submodules. Once things get too complicated, there are too many things that can go wrong.

Use a package manager instead, like [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/) or [Paket](https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/). Those will also help with ensuring that only a single revision is used across all the projects, help to [resolve the revision that can be used](https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/resolver.html) for all the dependencies and provide tools to update the packages.

With NuGet you will have to create packages out of `A` and `B`, Paket allows [git dependecies](https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/git-dependencies.html), so you will only have to update build/project/solutions in `B` and `C`.