# manage big submodule which is used by multiple project repos on the same machine

Tags: git, symlink, mount

I have a submodule called **sub1** which is used by multiple project repos (e.g.: **proj1**, **proj2**, **proj3**, etc.):
[image]
sub1 is a pretty big submodule.

Each time I create a new project, it has to contain the sub1 submodule, which heavily increase the memory usage on my hard drive.

Is there a way to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `--reference` clones or add work trees to have multiple checkouts from just one copy of the object db, or if everybody's always on some particular submodule version [you can share a single checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27379818/git-possible-to-use-same-submodule-working-copy-by-multiple-projects/27384763#27384763).