# Sharing a submodule between projects without duplicating the submodule files

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a following program structure:

```
Program /
        |- LibA /
        |       |- SharedLib
        |
        |- LibB /
        |       |- SharedLib
        |
        |- LibC /
        |       |- SharedLib
        |
        |- ... /
        |      |- SharedLib
        |
        |- LibZ /
        |       |- SharedLib
        |
        |- SharedLib
```

`LibsA-Z` are libraries used to control external hardware. They're "standalone" libraries used by both my program and some external applications, so they must exist as separate projects & repositories. They're also very numerous (with more to come in the future) and they all reference the library `SharedLib` that provides some interfaces and other elements they rely on.

`SharedLib` is also a separate project/repository and I would like to include it as a submodule in the other libraries. The problem with this approach is that I would then have over a dozen of duplicate `SharedLib` submodules locally and would have to repeatedly fetch/pull the same files dozens of times after every adjustment to `SharedLib`.

Is there a way to make my program's submodule structure less wonky?

---

I have seen some potential fixes for this issue ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27379818/git-possible-to-use-same-submodule-working-copy-by-multiple-projects)), but I'm unsure about how reproducible they are (e.g., if someone pulls my `Program` repository, will they have to redo all the steps I had to do?). I also failed to find any official/recommended approaches to this issue.

Comment: "*if someone pulls my Program repository, will they have to redo all the steps I had to do?*" Alas, yes. There is no easy way to share submodule's worktrees. "*I also failed to find any official/recommended approaches to this issue.*" There are no any official recommendations; There is a non-official recommendation: forget; stop thinking about it. The only known solution is to use symlinks, but the solution is not reproducible.

Comment: Another approach is to stop using Git as a distribution tool (it's a development one), stop using submodules as a cheap replacement for package management and use a real package installer to install a single shared copy of a library.

Comment: @phd Perhaps I'm misunderstanding just what exactly "distribution" means, but I'm currently using Git only as a development tool. I see no problem in packing my libraries up in the future, but this does not seem like a good solution right now, while the libraries still undergo extensive debugging and are yet to be released.

Comment: Then the answer is: be content with what `git clone` gives you.